# Button Array - how to pass a parameter to shared handler

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a bit of code where i have a dynamically created array or buttons with staff pictures on them, as well as the staff's name. I've added one handler to handle any button click from any of the buttons. where i am stuck is, if you look at the code below, it all works fine, and if you click any of the buttons you get the "aha" test message. but i want the name of the staff clicked on (so btnArray(i).Text) to be passed to the handler for further processing. I tried adding a ByVal parameter to the handler but that caused an error. what's the correct way to do this? As i said, the code below works for me, i just am at a loss as to how to add the extra functionality.

```
        Dim btnArray(staffcount) As System.Windows.Forms.Button
    For i As Integer = 1 To staffcount - 1
        btnArray(i) = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
        btnArray(i).Visible = True
        btnArray(i).Width = 80
        btnArray(i).Height = 101
        btnArray(i).BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(picloc(i))
        btnArray(i).BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
        btnArray(i).Text = staffname(i)
        Dim who As String
        who = btnArray(i).Text
        AddHandler btnArray(i).Click, AddressOf Me.theButton_Click
        btnArray(i).ForeColor = Color.White
        btnArray(i).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter

        Dim fnt As Font

        fnt = btnArray(i).Font

        btnArray(i).Font = New Font(fnt.Name, 10, FontStyle.Bold)


        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btnArray(i))
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub theButton_Click()
    MsgBox("aha")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, correct the signature of your shared handler.

```
Private Sub theButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

Once that is done getting the text of the button clicked is a simple matter.

```
Private Sub theButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim textOfButtonClicked As String = DirectCast(sender, Button).Text
    MessageBox.Show(textOfButtonClicked)
End Sub
```

The sender is the button that was clicked.  Since signatures use objects for the sender the DirectCast 'changes' it to button and you then can access the .Text property of the button.

If there are more manipulations you want to perform on the clicked button you could do it this way

```
Private Sub theButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim whBtn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) ' get reference to button clicked
    Dim textOfButtonClicked As String = whBtn.Text
    MessageBox.Show(textOfButtonClicked)
    'e.g. change the color
    whBtn.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
End Sub
```